# Kafka consumer is receiving messages but they don't have any content?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have setup a consumer for my topic. I'm not trying to consume.

```
                    SetKeyDeserializer(Confluent.Kafka.Deserializers.Utf8).
                    SetValueDeserializer(new FileObjectDeserializer<string>()).
                    Build();
consumer.Consume(timeoutms)
```

I see the consumer being triggered as though data is coming.

The problem is that when I try to get the key or value I get nothing back. Both fields are just empty.

Tried to send the data like this

```
kafka_2.13-2.8.1/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic dynsig-in --bootstrap-server b-2.[...]:9092 --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=|"
>test|{}
```

Comment: What is `FileObjectDeserializer`?